# GGPLOT - two curves in one plot in B_W mode

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have the following piece of code, which I am writing to generate a Black and White image for my article in a paper.

```
require(ggplot2) 
require(extrafont)

#loadfonts(device="pdf")

#set the x-axis now 
xaxis <- seq(0,1, by=0.01)

#set the functions here 
aij <- sqrt(1 - (1-xaxis)**1.02)
bij <- 1 - (1 - xaxis)**1.50 

#plot using commands 

ggplot(,aes(xaxis)) + geom_line(aes(y=aij, colour="aij")) + 
      geom_line(aes(y=bij,colour="bij"),linetype="dashed") + 
      theme_bw() + 
      xlab("x ratio") + 
      ylab("Function values") + 
      theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12))
ggsave('myGraph.pdf')
```

Incidentally, I observe the following:

(1) The legend title needs to be gone
(2) The figure needs to be in Black and White 
(3) I need one curve in continuous line (aij) and the other in dashed form (bij).

What needs to be added to the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)

```
theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

(2)

```
scale_colour_manual(values = rep("black", 2))
```

(3)

```
scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed"))
```

All together e.g.:

```
ggplot(transform(stack(data.frame(aij, bij)), x = xaxis), 
       aes(x = x, y = values, linetype = ind)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab("x ratio") + 
  ylab("Function values") + 
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", face="bold", size=12), 
        legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed"))
```

which gives

[image]